# How to use LangChain to load the index generated by LlamaIndex and perform a query?

Tags: python, langchain, llama-index, py-langchain, large-language-model

I used `LlamaIndex` to generate an index for a section of text, which is stored in the myindex folder.
How should I use `LangChain` to load it and query it?

At present, I can only use `LlamaIndex` for querying, but this will lack the functionality of `LangChain` (such as Prompts, Chains, Agents).

build.py:

```
from llama_index import (
    Document,
    VectorStoreIndex
)
from langchain import OpenAI
import os.path as osp

text_list = ['Avery is a respiratory physician who specializes in addressing issues related to the novel coronavirus. His desire is for the number of patients in the world to decrease over time.']
documents = [Document(t) for t in text_list]

index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
index.storage_context.persist(persist_dir="myindex")
```

query.py:

```
from llama_index import StorageContext, load_index_from_storage

storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="myindex")
index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
print(query_engine.query("Who is Avery?"))
```

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

LlamaIndex provides adapters to do this sort of thing although I'm not sure if the existing adapters will satisfy all your requirements.

Here is an example of how you might use your index for your memory in a chat agent with LangChain:

```py
import os.path as osp

from langchain import OpenAI
from langchain.llms import OpenAIChat
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent

from llama_index import (
    Document,
    VectorStoreIndex
)
from llama_index.langchain_helpers.memory_wrapper import GPTIndexChatMemory



# options here aren't well documented - you'll need to dig through the code
# but I'll share some links below
memory = GPTIndexChatMemory(
    # internally converts to query engine via `as_query_engine`
    index=index,
    # or whatever is appropriate for you here - defaults to "history"
    memory_key="chat_history",
    # return_source returns source nodes instead of querying index
    return_source=True,
    # return_messages returns context (message history) as an array
    # of messages as opposed to a concatenated string of all message content
    return_messages=True,
)

llm = OpenAIChat(temperature=0)
# llm=OpenAI(temperature=0)
agent_chain = initialize_agent(
    [], llm, agent="conversational-react-description", memory=memory
)

agent_chain.run(input="Who is Avery?")
```

You can also use LlamaIndex as a LangChain tool.

some relevant links:

- [LangChain Memory Wrapper / `return_source` / `return_messages`](https://github.com/jerryjliu/llama_index/blob/a8066355231d6d4fdf35d1a4440bdf590399329e/llama_index/langchain_helpers/memory_wrapper.py#L147)
- [LlamaIndex <> LangChain Integrations Notebook](https://github.com/jerryjliu/llama_index/blob/main/examples/langchain_demo/LangchainDemo.ipynb)
- [More Advanced Integration Example w/ LangChain Tool + Custom LlamaIndex Query Engine](https://github.com/jerryjliu/llama_index/blob/main/examples/chatbot/Chatbot_SEC.ipynb)